# $\lim_{p\rightarrow 0}\int_X|f|^p\,d\mu=\mu(\{x\in X\,|\,f(x)\ne 0\})$

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, lebesgue-integral, lp-spaces

Let $(X,\mathscr{M},\mu)$ be a measure space and $f$ be an essentially bounded function, i.e. $f\in L^{\infty}$. How do I show that

> $\lim_{p\rightarrow 0}\int_X|f|^p\,d\mu=\mu(\{x\in X\,|\,f(x)\ne 0\})$.

In the cases where $f\in L^{p_0}$ for some $0<p_0<\infty$, the monotone/dominated convergence theorems show that this is indeed the case. But I don't see how I should proceed when $f$ is in $L^{\infty}$. Any advice?

Comment: Surely $X$ is a finite measure space?

Comment: If $f$ is in no $L^p$, the LHS is infinite hence you simply have to check that $\mu(f\ne0)=\infty$. Now, $f$ is bounded, hence...

Comment: @OpenBall No. $ $

Comment: Sorry, somehow saw that as $\left(\int |f|\right)^p$.

Comment: @Did : Oh, it was very simple after all. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We may assume that $f$ is not in $L^p$ for any $0<p<\infty$. Then the LHS is just $\infty$ so we only have to check that $\mu(\{f\ne0\})=\infty$. But, if $\mu(\{f\ne0\})$ is finite, then $\Vert f\Vert_1\leq \Vert f\Vert_{\infty}\mu(\{f\ne0\})$ hence $f$ is in $L^1$, a contradiction.